# Set individual text colors for separate Value Labels in LineDataSet

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to set different colors for each Value label in my LineDataSet. In my instance, many of the values presented will end up being zero. In this case I'd like to hide the labels, potentially by setting the value's text color to transparent.

I know it is possible to set one color for all of the labels through the `LineDataSet.setValueTextColor()` method. However, this only sets a color for all of the labels, not individual labels.

In the screenshot below you can see my current graph. I'd need labels with a zero value hidden.

I'd really appreciate any tips with this!

[image: Labels with a value of Zero are still show, but I'd like those hidden]

Comment: Highlighting and user interaction is disabled for my graph. I don't think highlight color is what I'm after. Unless there is a way to highlight every value, set individual highlight colors and then disable user interaction?

Comment: Yes. you can highlight a hightlight[].likely Chart.highlightvalues(hightlight[])

Comment: I have it now highlighting individual points, but there doesn't seem to be a handle to these points value labels.

Comment: Maybe label has Similar function.I have no code by hand.I'm going to bed

Comment: Use `MarkerView` to specifically style selected values.

Comment: I did this and it worked, thanks! Oh, and thank you for the wonderful library. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a [`ValueFormatter`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface)?

```
public class GreaterThanZeroValueFormatter implements ValueFormatter {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        if (value > 0) {
            return String.valueOf(value);
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// usage on whole data object
lineData.setValueFormatter(new GreaterThanZeroValueFormatter());

// usage on individual dataset object
lineDataSet.setValueFormatter(new GreaterThanZeroValueFormatter());
```

Comment: I bet this would have worked. I accomplished it using the MarkerView as Philip Jahoda suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, while I'm pretty sure Cory's answer would have worked quicker and easier, I'm going to post what I did here for posterity. I managed this using the powerful and convenient MarkerView that comes with MPAndroidChart.

First I called a function to highlight all points with values above 0.

```
private void highlightLinePoints(){
    List<Entry> entries = mLineChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0).getYVals();
    ArrayList<Highlight> indexes = new ArrayList<Highlight>();
    int i = 0;
    while (i<entries.size()){
        if (entries.get(i).getVal()>0 ){
            indexes.add(new Highlight(i,0));
        }
        i++;
    }
    Highlight[] highlights = new Highlight[indexes.size()];
    int e = 0;
    while(e<indexes.size()){
        highlights[e] = indexes.get(e);
        e++;
    }

    mLineChart.highlightValues(highlights);

}
```

[After that, I subclassed MarkerView following this excellent guide](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/MarkerView).

Once I had an xml layout setup and the MarkerView subclassed with my custom MarkerView, it was as easy as assigning the custom MarkerView class to my LineChart.

```
highlightLinePoints();

dataMarkerView dmv =  new dataMarkerView(getContext(), R.layout.data_marker_view);
mLineChart.setMarkerView(dmv);
```

My subclass is essentially the same as what's provided in the documentation.

[image: The fruits of my labor!]